# feature selection for Naive Bayes

Tags: r, naivebayes

I did a classification with Naive Bayes. The goal is to predict 4 factors through a text. The data looks like this:

```
 'data.frame':  387 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ reviewText: chr  "I love this. I have a D800. I am mention my camera to make sure that you understand that this product is not ju"| __truncated__ "I hate buying larger gig memory cards - because there's always that greater risk of losing the photos, and/or r"| __truncated__ "These chromebooks are really a pretty nice idea -- Almost no maintaince (no maintaince?), no moving parts, smal"| __truncated__ "Purchased, as this drive allows a much speedier read/write and is just below a full SSD (they need to drop the "| __truncated__ ...
 $ pragmatic : Factor w/ 4 levels "-1","0","1","9": 4 4 4 3 3 4 3 3 3...
```

I did the classification with the `caret` package. The code for the classification looks like this:

```
sms_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sms_raw$text))
sms_corpus_clean <- sms_corpus %>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>% 
    tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
    tm_map(removeWords, stopwords(kind="en")) %>%
    tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
    tm_map(stripWhitespace)
sms_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_clean)

train_index <- createDataPartition(sms_raw$type, p=0.5, list=FALSE)
sms_raw_train <- sms_raw[train_index,]
sms_raw_test <- sms_raw[-train_index,]
sms_corpus_clean_train <- sms_corpus_clean[train_index]
sms_corpus_clean_test <- sms_corpus_clean[-train_index]
sms_dtm_train <- sms_dtm[train_index,]
sms_dtm_test <- sms_dtm[-train_index,]

sms_dict <- findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train, lowfreq= 5) 
sms_train <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_clean_train, list(dictionary=sms_dict))
sms_test <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_clean_test, list(dictionary=sms_dict))

convert_counts <- function(x) {
    x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
    x <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Absent", "Present"))
}
sms_train <- sms_train %>% apply(MARGIN=2, FUN=convert_counts)
sms_test <- sms_test %>% apply(MARGIN=2, FUN=convert_counts)


ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", 10)
set.seed(8)
sms_model1 <- train(sms_train, sms_raw_train$type, method="nb",
                trControl=ctrl)


sms_predict1 <- predict(sms_model1, sms_test)
cm1 <- confusionMatrix(sms_predict1, sms_raw_test$type)
```

When I use this model in that way which means the I do the prediction for all of the 4 variables at the same time I get a low `Accuracy:0.5469`, The confusion matrix looks like this.

```
          Reference
Prediction -1  0  1  9
        -1  0  0  1  0
        0   0  0  0  0
        1   9  5 33 25
        9  11  3 33 72
```

When I do the prediction for all of the 4 variables separately I get a much better result. The code for the classification is the same as above but instead of `df$sensorial <- factor(df$sensorial)` I do `df$sensorial <- as.factor(df$sensorial == 9)`. For the other variables, I use `1`,`-1` or `0` instead of the `9`. If I do it that way I get an `Accuracy: 0.772` for the `9`, an `Accuracy:0.829` for the `-1`, an `Accuracy:0.9016` for the `0` and an `Accuracy:0.7959`  for the `1`. In Addition, the result is far better. So it must have something to do with feature selection. The reason for the different results might be the features are often the same for the different values. So, a possible solution could be to give those feature more importance which occurs just in presence of a certain value but not in presence of the others. Is there a way to select the features in such a way, so that the model will be better if I do the prediction for all the 4 variables simultaneously? Something like a weighted term-document-matrix?

**Edit:**

I calculated the weights for the four values like Cihan Ceyhan told:

```
prop.table(table(sms_raw_train$type))
         -1           0           1           9 
0.025773196 0.005154639 0.180412371 0.788659794 

modelweights <- ifelse(sms_raw_train$type == -1, 
             (1/table(sms_raw_train$type)[1]) * 0.25, 
             ifelse(sms_raw_train$type == 0, 
             (1/table(sms_raw_train$type)[2]) * 0.25,
             ifelse(sms_raw_train$type == 1, 
             (1/table(sms_raw_train$type)[3]) * 0.25,
             ifelse(sms_raw_train$type == 9, 
             (1/table(sms_raw_train$type)[4]) * 0.25,9))))
```

But the result is not better `Accuracy:0.5677`

```
              Reference
    Prediction -1  0  1  9
            -1  1  0  1  1
            0   1  0  1  0
            1  11  3 32 20
            9   7  5 33 76
```

So, maybe it´s a better idea to calculate the results for every value separately an then sum the results up like in the second solution that was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accuracy is a  misleading metric to use here. In the multilabel confusion matrix you have posted, you have ~89% accuracy if you only look at label `-1` versus `others`. Because you predict `-1` only once, and missclasify `-1`'s as `others` 20 times (9+11). For all other cases, you classify the `-1` vs `others` problem correctly, so `170/191=89%` accuracy. But of course this doesn't mean the model is working as intended; it is just printing `others` to almost all cases. This mechanic is also the reason why you see higher accuracy numbers in the single label classifications.

See [here](http://www.chioka.in/class-imbalance-problem/) for a good overview on the class imbalance problem, and potential ways to mitigate it.

Also this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99667/naive-bayes-with-unbalanced-classes) is very relevant to your case, so I suggest you take a look.

Comment: Thaks for the links. Your right. When I look at recall and precision for the overall prediction the results for the values -9, 0, -1 are really bad. Following the information in the links, you have posted the most effective way would be to transform the term frequency through oversampling and undersampling.  But I have no Idea how to do that in r. It seems there is no package available for that operation.

Comment: In the thread you posted, the guy (which had the same problem) did the classification for every value separately (like I did). Do you think this would be the best solution right now?

Comment: @Banjo With the `caret` library you are using, there are very easy to use implementations of class imbalance fixers. See here for a tutorial: https://www.r-bloggers.com/handling-class-imbalance-with-r-and-caret-an-introduction/

Comment: For your second question, it shouldn't matter [because naive bayes extends trivially to multiclass classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142505/how-to-use-naive-bayes-for-multi-class-problems).